# in non-separable Hilbert spaces, is the adjoint of a $p$-Schatten class operator again $p$-Schatten class with the same norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $T \colon U \to V$ is an operator of Schatten class $p$ between two separable Hilbert spaces $U$ and $V$, it follows directly from the fact that the singular values of an operator and its adjoint agree that the adjoint $T^{\ast}$ is of Schatten class $p$ as well and $\lVert T \rVert_p = \lVert T^{\ast} \rVert_p$.

Does the situation change if the Hilbert spaces are non-separable? If I interpret the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) correctly, the Schatten norms are no longer defined in terms of singular values but instead of traces of powers of the absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Schatten  class operator is compact, and every compact operator *lives* on  separable spaces.

By this I mean that there are closed, separable subspaces $U_0\subseteq U$, and $V_0\subseteq V$, such
that

- $T=0$ on $U_0^\perp$,  and
- $\text{Ran}(T)\subseteq V_0$.

Thus, if we define $T_0$ to be the restriction of $T$ to $U_0$, then
$$
  T=T_0\oplus 0 :  U_0\oplus U_0^\perp \to   V_0\oplus V_0^\perp.
  $$

Using this,  one may easily generalize  all of the machinery developed to deal with  operators on
separable spaces to non-separable ones.

In particular,  yes,   the singular values of a $p$-Schatten class  operator and its adjoint agree, and hence
$\|T^*\|_p = \|T\|_p$.

Comment: Thank you very much!